# How to install tmux 2.2+ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, tmux

I git cloned tmux from github, tag 2.2 and run `sh autogen.sh` and `./configure && make`. For the last one I had to install `automake`. I also have all the dependencies I found required. When I try to run `sudo make install` I got

```
$ sudo make install                                                                                                                                         [22:58:28]
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kode/tmux-2.2'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c tmux '/usr/local/bin'
make  install-exec-hook
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kode/tmux-2.2'
if test xmdoc = xmdoc; then \
    sed -e "s|@SYSCONFDIR@|/etc|g" ./tmux.1 \
        >./tmux.1.mdoc; \
else \
    sed -e "s|@SYSCONFDIR@|/etc|g" ./tmux.1| \
        mawk -f./mdoc2man.awk >./tmux.1.man; \
fi
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./tmux.1.mdoc \
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/tmux.1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kode/tmux-2.2'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kode/tmux-2.2'
```

How to fix this and install tmux 2.2+?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any error messages. The installations appears successful.

Comment: Thats Right. I dont know why I decided the output was an error message. Maybe I expected more to see something similar like ok or success at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you DID install `tmux` in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
/usr/bin/install -c tmux '/usr/local/bin'
```

and `tmux.1` in `/usr/local/share/man/man1/tmux.1`

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./tmux.1.mdoc \
/usr/local/share/man/man1/tmux.1
```

You can now `man tmux`, and `type -p tmux`, and even `tmux`, if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`.